# How to set canonical link for website with www redirection

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, rel-canonical, no-www, www

I am confused about adding canonical link in my website.

I have a website `https://example.com` and I have added Redirect to `www` from hosting provider(firebase) config.

So if a user accesses my non-www `https://example.com`, it will automatically redirect to `https://www.example.com`.

For the purpose of SEO I have added canonical link in header as follows

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/">
```

Is the above canonical link is correct?

Comment: Your additional question about trailing slashes is answered here: [Should I add a trailing slash to my canonical link or not?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49487/should-i-add-a-trailing-slash-to-my-canonical-link-or-not) so I edited it out of your question

Answer (score 1):

The canonical is correct as long as there is only one and all URLs that access page show the same canonical. It is your choice as to which one but it is definitely best-practice that the canonical matches the redirect.

Remember that Googlebot also follows redirects, so if you have setup a *Permanent Redirect*, then there is only one visitable URL anyway. If you redirect to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) without changing the protocol and you users are able to visit http://www.example.com and https://www.example.com then having the canonical is important but if all end up on the same URL, then the canonical is not really needed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is canonical link is set correctly.